# Manipulating arm assembly macro parameters

Tags: assembly, macros, arm

Hello I have an arm macro for

```
DO_STUFF $reg1,$reg2,scal

  vmull.s16 $reg2,$reg1,$scal

ENDM
```

If I pass `$reg2` as a `Q` register and `$reg1` as a `D` register, every thing is fine. But Suppose i want to pass `$reg1` also as a `Q` register and do mutliplication on lower half of it. Ie if I pass `Q0` I want to do multiplication on `D0`. How can I do it. I want some method that will not affect performance, ie some assembler directives.

I have tried using string manipulation, as per ARM documentation

```
improb SETS "literal":CC:(strvar2:LEFT:4)

; sets the variable improbto the value "literal"
; with the left-most four characters of the
; contents of string variable strvar2appended
```

I tried using

```
dreg1 SETS "d":REVERSE_CC:($reg1:RIGHT:1)
```

to extract the name of `D` register. But it did not assemble.
Any help ?

Comment: Note the obvious difference between the documentation you quoted and your code below it: why replace the ["concatenate strings" operator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731181182.html) with the ["invert condition code" operator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731178867.html)?

Comment: @Notlikethat The invert condition operator was used because in the documentation we are extracting 4 characters from left. Now to do what I want, I will have to get the number part in the register name. Which can be 1 or 2 digits, ie like q0 and q11. Thus I have to find some way to overcome this. That's why i used  "invert condition code" operator. ie to get invert of 1 character from right, equivalent to all characters except the right most one. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My point is, what relevance do condition codes have to anything here? `:REVERSE_CC:` is for e.g. turning "ne" into "eq", it has nothing to do with concatenating strings. And the concatenation isn't the issue anyway, you just need to generalise from the rightmost 1 character (which works fine for the single-digit example in the question, hence the confusion), to the rightmost _n_-1 characters, where _n_ is the length of the string. Hopefully you've already noticed the `:LEN:` operator ;)